# How to install 22.04 Server with HWE

Tags: server, system-installation, kernel

I am trying to install Ubuntu 22.04 on a system that requires an HWE kernel. It appears the "Boot and Install with HWE Kernel" option is not present on the 22.04 installer like it was on the 20.04 and previous versions.

How does one accomplish a clean install of Ubuntu 22.04 with the Ubuntu 22.04 Server ISO if an HWE kernel is needed?

Currently I am installing 20.04 with HWE kernel and upgrading to 22.04.

Where is the HWE option on the 22.04 ISO?

If it is not available is there another option to installing 22.04 with HWE without manual upgrade?

Comment: The HWE ISOs usually start with the second point release - 22.04.2, which is expected in January 2023. For now, the only kernel available for 22.04 is the default kernel 5.15.

Answer (score 0):

After doing a clean install you can install the HWE kernel with.

```
sudo apt install linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04
```

After that reboot and from grub options choose the new kernel.

Comment: This is entirely unhelpful when you can't install the OS with the stock kernel at all; say because that kernel is lacking hardware support for your storage system.